# Sqlite3 with task scheduler or schedule task using command prompt

Tags: sqlite, command, task, scheduler, prompt

I would like to run the folloiwng command in 
1.**task scheduler** 
or 
2. **on scheduled task using Command Prompt**.
sqlite3 database.sqlite < commands.txt

commands.txt is

**.headers off
.mode csv
.output test.csv
SELECT SELECT json_extract(data, '$.patient._id','$.patient.created_on') FROM dataset;
.exit**

As method 1, I'm not able to run on **task scheduler**.

As method 2,I used batch file for scheduled task using Command Prompt.
My batch file is (**test.bat**)
**@echo on
sqlite3 database.sqlite < commands.txt
pause**

It point to under **C:\Windows\System32>** (**Run as administrator**)and got the error like **Error: near line 4: no such table: dataset**

Method 1 is working under command prompt by typing **C:\Users\kk>database.sqlite < commands.txt**.
Method 2 is also working at **C:\Users\kk>test.bat**.
But both methods can't work at **task scheduler or on scheduled task using Command Prompt**.

Please teach me how to.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Probably because the database lives in `C:\usersk\kk`. Try adding a `cd` to that directory in the beginning of `test.bat`

Comment: Thanks. Is it able to run in sleep mode or hibernate or shutdown if I use command prompt ?

Comment: That's a completely different question, and I don't know the answer.